# Q:enter text in \ part

Tags: parts

I am making a text that consists of 4 chapters and I add parts to it, and I would like to see text in the parts as an introduction, as I introduce text to the parties?,
Thank you

Comment: Do you want `\part{}`?

Comment: when I use that \ part {} it only appears
"part I"
"first part"
I would like to add more text to this

Comment: After `\part{title here}` insert your text before the first `\chapter{title here}`.